# Единственное или множественное число глагола?

Tags: согласование, глаголы, окончания, единственное-множественное-число

*Все может измениться, если в неспешный ритм жизни приход**ит (ят)** безысходность **и / или** отчаяние — все то, что нарушает ее привычный ход, лишает надежды и уверенности.*

Какое окончание у глагола "приходить": **"ит"** или **"ят"**?
Склоняюсь к множественному числу, но не помешала бы ссылка на правило.
Влияет ли как-то изменение союзов: **"и"** на **"или"**?

Comment: «Приходи(Я)т, безысходность, ход». Склоняетесь к множественному числу?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос касается согласования сказуемого (приходит) с однородными подлежащими (безысходность И/ИЛИ отчаяние). Розенталь пишет, это при обратном порядке (сказуемое предшествует подлежащим) обычно употребляется форма единственного числа. Например:

*До Райского и Марфиньки долетел грубый говор, грубый смех, смешанные голоса, внезапно притихшие... (Гончаров); Появилась ломота во всех членах и мучительная головная боль (Тургенев); Несся тяжелый топот кованых сапог и крикливые бабьи взвизги... (Серафимович); По земле, истомленной в зное, разливалась свежесть, прохлада и неизъяснимая легкость... (В.Солоухин).*

Но он же указывает, что это положение не носит категорического характера. Иногда используется форма множественного числа препозитивного сказуемого, что подчеркивает множественность предметов.

См: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm (§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими)

В случае с "и" я бы поставил множественное число, подчеркивая, что речь идет о нескольких "состояниях души", тем более что далее следует обобщающее слово "все".

**Все может измениться, если в неспешный ритм жизни приходЯт безысходность И отчаяние — *ВСЕ* то, что нарушает ее привычный ход, лишает надежды и уверенности.**

Именно из-за этого "все" мне кажется неуместным союз "или". И еще, безысходность и отчаяние - близкие понятия, поэтому я бы не стал соединять их союзом "или". Но если проигнирировать близость этих понятий, убрать "все" и поставить "или", то тогда однозначно требуется сказуемое в единственном числе.

**Все может измениться, если в неспешный ритм жизни приходИт безысходность ИЛИ отчаяние — то, что нарушает ее привычный ход, лишает надежды и уверенности.**

P.S.
Наличие трех однокоренных слов (приходит, безысходность и ход) и двух "все" не украшает это предложение, но это уже другая тема

Answer (score 0):

Правил пруд пруди, а "моего" не обнаруживается: множественное число сказуемого при существительных *разного рода*.

Во всяком случае, источники единодушны в том, что для приведённого Вами примера нет категорического правила. То есть как душеньке угодно будет.

Наше всё - Розенталь:

> Форма множественного числа препозитивного сказуемого подчеркивает
>   множественность предметов, например: *Слышатся кашель и стук* (Чехов);
>   *Снаружи были слышны визг, лай и вой* (Арсеньев).

См. [§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими.](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_08)

Другие толкователи (сновидений):

Валгина, присуседившаяся к Розенталю и осовременившая оного:

[305.1. Форма сказуемого при однородных подлежащих.](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-167.htm)

Грамота.ру, сократившая километры правил, не потеряв сути:

[Единственное и множественное число сказуемого.](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo)

---

А *и* и *или* конечно влияют на результат.

> Формы сказуемого зависят от значения союзов при однородных подлежащих.
>
> При наличии соединительных союзов обычно наблюдаются указанные выше
>   формы сказуемых.
>
> При наличии разделительных союзов сказуемое обычно ставится в форме
>   единственного числа, например: *Пережитый страх или мгновенный испуг
>   уже через минуту кажется и смешным, и странным, и непонятным* (Фурм.).
>
> ---

- "Выше" - это валгинский 305.1.